# App store rejected the app saying about adding apple sign in and in-app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, flutter-ios

I had developed a flutter application using the conventional sign in method and 3 social logins(google/facebook/twitter). It had a subscription plan(not an auto renewal) costing only 2$ per month to get rid of the ad. It was successfully updated in the google play store but the app store review they continuously rejected it. I had given an appeal to them about the working of the application but still they rejected it.
the rejected things are as follows

```
Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase


We noticed that your app still includes or accesses paid digital content, services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

Specifically, we noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other than in-app purchase.
```

and the second one

```
Guideline 4.8 - Design - Sign in with Apple


Your app still uses a third-party login service, but does not offer Sign in with Apple. Apps that use a third-party login service for account authentication need to offer Sign in with Apple to users as an equivalent option.
```

my client doesn't want to add apple sign on in their app. and I had used stripe as payment gateway.

Is there anyone that can help me on this. I'm stuck here for more than 2 weeks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store rejection is off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what app do you develop, but all information you need is already in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

**3.1.1 In-App Purchase**

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

You should always use default in-app purchase mechanism provided by Apple if your app need to unlock some functions such as subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version.

Just a little more context for you, Fortnite game was kicked-off from App Store in 2020 just because the developer (Epic Games) implemented their-owned in-app purchase into the game to unlock some functionality, such as in-game items. Source: [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/13/21366438/apple-fortnite-ios-app-store-violations-epic-payments).

**4.8 Sign in with Apple**

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.

If you use third-party or social login service such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login, you **SHOULD INCLUDE** Sign in with Apple. But if you use **your company’s sign-in system** so Sign in with Apple is **not required**.

I have some experience with this before. I include Google Signin but not include Sign in with Apple, and it got rejected.

Comment: The app I had developed is an invoice saver app, the premium version is only used for ad free . so you are suggesting change my stripe payment gateway to in app purchase and i should app apple sign in . so there is no other way?

Comment: Correct. You can only use non-Apple payment providers if you're selling physical goods. Since what you're trying to sell is only software, you're required to use Apple's IAPs. As for Sign in with Apple, yes, you're required to offer it if you offer other 3rd party sign in services, which you are.

Comment: @james Yes, I am afraid there is no way other than get rid your / your company's payment method, use only Apple's in-app purchase method, and adding Sign in with Apple.

Comment: OK thanks all I had updated the code and it is pending in review